# curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer | curl error | Golang TCP server

Tags: go, http, curl, tcp

Getting this error message when trying to hit a curl on to a local server created using Golang :

```
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

I am trying to write a TCP server code using Golang(code is mentioned below). Ideally when you run this code, the server should start running, which is happening successfully. But when I am trying to hit the following curl request : `curl http://localhost:1729`, I am getting `Recv failure: Connection reset by peer` error.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
)

func main() {
    listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":1729")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    conn, err := listener.Accept()
    // fmt.Println("Waiting for connection")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(conn)
}
```

Comment: What else did you expect to happen? The program accepts the connection then exits.

Comment: I am expecting the program to accept the connection, print the value of conn and then exit. But nothing gets printed. When the request is being hit, the program exits with the Error mentioned.

Comment: The error you show is not printed by your program, it's printed by `curl`. Your program did exactly what you describe, accepted the connection then printed the value of `conn` (which won't be anything useful, it would look something like `&{{0x1234567890}}`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Connection reset by peer" will happen if the server closes the connection while there are still unread data from the client (among other causes). In this case a TCP RST is sent. This is exactly what is happening here: curl is sending a HTTP request but the server does not read it but instead immediately closes the connection.